# MultivariateOptimizer is abstract; cannot be instantiated error when trying to optimize a function in Java

Tags: java, optimization

Ok I'm trying optimize a Poisson likelihood function and I'm getting the error: "MultivariateOptimizer is abstract; cannot be instantiated", below is my code:

```
    package javaapplication1;

    import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.MultivariateFunction;
    import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.BaseOptimizer;
    import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.InitialGuess;
    import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.MaxEval;
    import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.PointValuePair;
    import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.SimpleBounds;
    import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.GoalType;
    import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.MultivariateOptimizer;
    import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.ObjectiveFunction;
    import org.apache.commons.math3.optimization.direct.BOBYQAOptimizer;
    import org.apache.commons.math3.optimization.direct.CMAESOptimizer;



 public class JavaApplication1 {


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // x_input generated from Poisson(3)
    double x_input[]={3,0,4,3,4,4,3,2,3,0};
    // x_input generated from Poisson(3)

   // maximization effort

    MultivariateFunction f;
    f = (double[] lam) -> (poisson_loglik(lam,x_input));
    MultivariateOptimizer optim= new BOBYQAOptimizer(x_input.length * 2);;
    PointValuePair result;
    result = optim.optimize(new MaxEval(1000),
            new ObjectiveFunction(f),
            GoalType.MAXIMIZE,
            new InitialGuess(new double[] {3})
    );

   // maximization effort


    //Initializing Poisson's lamda value 
    double theta_input[]={3};
    //Initializing Poisson's lamda value 

    //Just checking if the functions are well defined
    System.out.println(factorial(3));
    System.out.println(poisson_pdf(3,3));
    System.out.println(poisson_loglik(theta_input,x_input));
    //Just checking if the functions are well defined


}


 //   Defining function to compute the factorial 
    public static  double factorial(double n){
      double sum=0;
      for (double i=1; i<=n; i++) sum=sum+Math.log(i);
      return Math.exp(sum);
     }
 //   Defining function to compute the factorial 

 //   Defining the poisson pdf   
    public static  double poisson_pdf(double x, double lamda){
       return (1/factorial(x)) * (Math.pow(lamda,x)) * (Math.exp(-lamda) ) ;
    }
 //   Defining the poisson pdf 

 //   Defining the poisson loglikelihood which I want to optimize somehow
public static double poisson_loglik(double theta[], double x[]){
    double lamda_pois=theta[0];
    double loglik_result=0;
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++) loglik_result=Math.log(poisson_pdf(x[i],lamda_pois))+loglik_result;
    return loglik_result;
}
 //   Defining the poisson loglikelihood which I want to optimize somehow 



}
```

I know that MultivariateOptimizer is an abstract class, but does anyone know how can I make it work? (edited with entire class) I'm using Net Beans and I'm new to java

Comment: do you mean this: MultivariateOptimizer optim= new CMAESOptimizer();?

Comment: Yes, but it looks like BOBYQAOptimizer is a better choice, because CMAESOptimizer needs a lot of arguments.

Comment: It tells me to import org.apache.commons.math3.optimization.direct.CMAESOptimizer, but when I do so the  CMAESOptimizer in the import is crossed with a line and it still doesn't work

Comment: The cross line means it is deprecated. See my answer.

Comment: now it throws me the error: 'org.apache.commons.math3.optimization.direct.BOBYQAOptimizer cannot be converted to org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.MultivariateOptimizer'

Comment: Can you post the entire class code? (including imports)

Comment: You have the wrong import, it should be org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.BOBYQAOptimizer

Comment: It say there is no such package/library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of it's concrete subclasses: BOBYQAOptimizer, CMAESOptimizer, GradientMultivariateOptimizer, LinearOptimizer, PowellOptimizer, SimplexOptimizer instead.

You can try this:

```
double x_input[]={3,0,4,3,4,4,3,2,3,0};
    // x_input generated from Poisson(3)


    MultivariateFunction f =(double[] lam) -> (poisson_loglik(lam,x_input));
    MultivariateOptimizer optim= new BOBYQAOptimizer(x_input.length * 2);
    PointValuePair result;
    result = optim.optimize(new MaxEval(1000),
            new ObjectiveFunction(f),
            GoalType.MAXIMIZE,
            new InitialGuess(new double[] {3})
    );
```

The argument of BOBYQAOptimizer constructor is the number of interpolation points. You can modify it accordingly.

Working example, you can modify it for your needs:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.MultivariateFunction;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.InitialGuess;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.MaxEval;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.PointValuePair;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.SimpleBounds;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.GoalType;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.ObjectiveFunction;
import org.apache.commons.math3.optim.nonlinear.scalar.noderiv.BOBYQAOptimizer;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MultivariateFunction fn = new MultivariateFunction() {
            @Override
            public double value(double[] point) {
                return 0;
            }
        };

        BOBYQAOptimizer optimizer = new BOBYQAOptimizer(2 * 3 + 1 + 2); // 2*point.length + 1+additional
        final PointValuePair optimum = optimizer.optimize(new MaxEval(150), new ObjectiveFunction(fn),
                GoalType.MAXIMIZE, new InitialGuess(new double[] { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 }),
                new SimpleBounds(new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 }, new double[] { 3.5, 3.5, 3.5 }));

        double[] point = optimum.getPoint();
        System.out.print("point= ");
        for (int i = 0; i < point.length; i++)
            System.out.print("  " + point[i]);
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("value = " + optimum.getValue());

    }

}
```

Comment: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: BOBYQAOptimizer.<init>

Comment: @Alex See my updated answer, pay attention to the imports.

Comment: Thanks I will try !

Comment: Finally!!! I used the PowellOptimizer though and it finally worked!!!! Thank you a lot, now I can create all types of regressions and mixture models with maximum likelihood parameter estimations in Java! I was searching the whole weekend!

Comment: @Alex You can accept the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: Accepted it !! :)